# Is there any gui to make a global (system and devices) search in Ubuntu?

Tags: system, search, devices

I've searched for this topic but it seems that I'm the only one with this problem.
The search for files default app allows to search only in a specific place. I would like to search, let's say, for a video in all my usb hd (4), in my home, in my video folder, sub folders, etc. at the same time. I need to see the preview of my video (or my videos sharing the same part of name). It's surprising for me that a "search in the computer" tool, largely used in other O.S., is not installed by default in Ubuntu. I'm using Ubuntu Mate 15.10. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try Catfish, it is very light and fast file searching GUI.

In the terminal do:

`sudo apt-get install catfish`

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in the past, thanks, but it's not what I need. It forces you to make a choice on where to search like the default search app. I don't want to make a choice, I want to search everywhere in my computer, system and devices, at the same time. Is this possible in Ubuntu using a graphical interface?